# How can I use utf-8 for my password in a smb connection?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm currently using the library smbprotocol to establish a smb connection with kerberos authentication. My problem is that I have a password with utf-8 characters and the connection can't be created. If I use another password with only ascii characters it works. How can I make it work? I'm currently just testing the library, so I used the official example, you can find it here:

https://github.com/jborean93/smbprotocol/blob/master/examples/low-level/file-management.py

Btw I'm using Python 2.7. I know it's outdated but I can't update at this point of time.

Comment: Why not use an ASCII password?

Comment: @Phineas Would u.encode("ascii","ignore") not just leave certain characters out? It would probably work if I want to decode a simple text, but my password would always come out wrong...

Comment: @Phineas good idea, but it didn't work.

Comment: In what format is your password? A string? In a file?

Comment: Currently it's hardcoded as a string, overall coding of the file is utf-8, later it should be inserted via xml file, but as said that is a "later"-problem :D

Comment: This maybe? `sascii = password.decode('utf-8').encode('ascii')` when password is a string

Comment: @Phineas that can't work. ASCII doesn't have all chars that can present with utf-8. E.g.: ASCII does not have `§`.